# BigQuery Standard SQL - Is there any workaround for not being able to save UDFs in views?

Tags: google-bigquery

When I try to save a view in StandardSQL using an user defined function, BigQuery gives the following error:

`Failed to save view. No support for CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION statements inside views`

I know it can be done with LegacySQL, but in my case I really need to use StandardSQL.

Does anyone know of any possible workarounds to this problem?

Comment: Please follow [the relevant issue tracker feature](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905921) for updates on persistent UDFs, which will be usable from logical views.